# Angular 4: Route Transition Loading

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to create a simple component that has a boolean flag `isLoading` that is `true` when a route has taken more than half a second to resolve.

I have the piece to turn it off:

```
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError)
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = false);
```

But how do I say:

```
    this.router.events
        //given a NavigationStart
        //If you don't see NavigationEnd/NavigationCancel/NavigationError within 500ms
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = true);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
this.router.events
        .debounceTime(500)
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = true);
```

What this says is:

`.debounceTime(500)` = if another event is created before 500 ms suppress me

`.filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)` = only take NavigateStart from the events that aren't followed with 500ms

`.subscribe(event => this.isLoading = true);` = we know now that it was a navigation start that was not followed within 500 ms so we can start the loading icon

Comment: I think that needs to be debounceTime opposed to debounce.  I just tried this out and it wasn't working for me:  the issue is several `RouteConfigLoadStart` and `RouteConfigLoadEnd` will be occurring during that loading period, which resets the debounce count

Comment: My apologies I thought the only events were NavigationStart/End/Cancel/Error.  Updating to debounceTime.  Is it possible you could give a thumbs up so I can get enough rep to make comments on stuff? haha

Answer (score 3):

I just did this, with no special timer:

```
 constructor(private authService: AuthService,
            private messageService: MessageService,
            private router: Router) {

    router.events.subscribe((routerEvent: Event) => {
        this.checkRouterEvent(routerEvent);
    });
 }

checkRouterEvent(routerEvent: Event): void {
    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationStart) {
        this.loading = true;
    }

    if (routerEvent instanceof NavigationEnd ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationCancel ||
        routerEvent instanceof NavigationError) {
        this.loading = false;
    }
}
```

And it works fine. If the route loads quickly, no spinner appears. If the route resolver takes a bit of time, the spinner appears.

This code is from the "Angular Routing" Pluralsight course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-routing

Comment: Thanks Deborah - I feel like this solution is dependent on the user's machine/browser as far as what they end up seeing.  I'd like to have more control over it with a specific debounce time if possible

Comment: the 500ms timeout will not be handled in this way. the best way is to use the rxjs .debounce(500)  as @KeniSteward suggested below. You can have a callback to handle manually the timeout but RxJs is already providing the function to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

I think for now I'm going to go with this solution:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let timer: any;

    this.router.events
        .subscribe(event => {
            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                timer = setTimeout(() => this.isLoading = true, 250);
            } else if (event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError) {
                clearTimeout(timer);
                this.isLoading = false;
            }
        });
}
```

If someone posts a cleaner RxJs way of going about it I'll note that

*edit*: Based on @KeniSteward's answer I was able to get this solution to work:

```
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError)
        .debounceTime(250)
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = true);

    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError)
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = false);
```

*edit #2*: Even cleaner -

```
    this.router.events
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd || event instanceof NavigationCancel || event instanceof NavigationError)
        .do(event => this.isLoading = false)
        .debounceTime(250)
        .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
        .subscribe(event => this.isLoading = true);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let isLoading: boolean = false;

ngOnInit() {
     this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
         if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
             this.isLoading = true;
         }
         if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
             this.isLoading = false;
         }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Each set of routing events have id. When id got changed - you need to toggle the spinner.